# Calculating number of digits in the integer part in a decimal number

Tags: apex

Currently I want to find out the number of digits in the integer part of a decimal number.

```
system.debug((895.95).intValue().format().length());
```

I am getting correct value as 3.

Just wanted to know if there is any direct function available or better way to do this ?

Comment: This approach you are taking will not work for any numbers greater than 1000: format() will add in commas (or other characters, depending on your user's locale).  For example, `system.debug((12895.95).intValue().format().length());` will return `6`.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

```
Decimal x = -85695.95;
system.debug(x.precision() + ' - ' + x.scale()); // you want (x.precision() - x.scale())
```

where [Decimal methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm):

> `scale()` Returns the scale of the Decimal, that is, the number of
>   decimal places.
>
> `precision()` Returns the total number of digits for
>   the Decimal.

Comment: I am getting the result as USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|5 - 2 . Does it actually subtract like that or any function needs to be used?

Comment: You have to do x.precision() - x.scale() that I have in the comments section.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, if you want to stick with numbers, this `Execute Anonymous` script illustrates a different approach.

```
static Integer length(Decimal input)
{
    return (input == 0) ? 1 : 1 + (Integer)Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(input)));
}
system.assertEquals(3, length(895.95));
```

Note that you `log10(0)` is infinity, so you need to handle that edge case. You can also add null handling if you wish. Anyway, `log10` basically gives you the number of tens places you have minus one. With negative numbers, you'll get a `NaN` value, so you have to take the absolute value.

Comment: Will add more explanation shortly.

Comment: Shouldn't the return be `(input == 0) ? 1 : 1 + (Integer)Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(input)));`?  The log function isn't defined for negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah adding that in my edit.

Comment: ...and this, ladies, gentlemen, and those identifying as non-binary, is what we call an elegant solution. On that note, if you're just adding one to the floor, why not use `Math.ceil()` instead?

Comment: It wouldn't give the correct result for values between 0 (exclusive) and 1 (inclusive).